# TFS Service maximum number of Team projects?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Team foundation Service (http://tfs.visualstudio.com/)
Which is the maximum number of Team projects that you can create on free version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently unlimited according to the [pricing](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/pricing/information) page. Right at the top where it says "What it includes", "Unlimited number of projects".